# Net::Libdnet-0.92 installation with ActiveState Perl

Tags: perl, network-programming

My production environemnt is activestate perl 5.8 for some reason i need this library 
net::libdnet [http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Libdnet](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aLibdnet)
Did someone know if there a ppm on activestate perl for installing this version of net::libdnet [http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Libdnet](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aLibdnet)
or if there another option to install this library under windows

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [list of PPMs](http://ppm4.activestate.com/idx/NETJ...NETS.html), it appears that all of the PPM builds for Net::Libdnet v0.92 have failed. You might be able to build it yourself if a) you have libdnet, and b) you have an environment in which you can build XS modules. If you're trying to install PPMs I'd wager that you have neither a) nor b), but it's worth a shot.